# How to read a file that is in use by other process?

Tags: delphi, winapi

I have an application that have a log system that create a file and keep it handle with a TFileStream, that is created with this way:
FFileStream := TFileStream.Create(FFilename, fmOpenWrite);

Ok. When I try to open this file with notepad, no problem, with notepad++ no problem. When I try to load the file with other application that I created it raise my an error that says the file is in used by other process.
I tried TStringList, LoadFromFile and TFileStream.Create(LFile, fmOpenRea);.

Some one knows how I can read this like the notepad and notepad++?

Tks.

Comment: you need to use the sharing flags. Pass in fmShareDenyWrite to the constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `fmOpenWrite or fmShareDenyNone` to enable sharing.

Answer (score 7):

Erik got there first but uses fmShareDenyNone which would allow other processes to write to the same file. If you only want to allow reading by other processes, use:

```
FFileStream := TFileStream.Create(FFilename, fmOpenWrite or fmShareDenyWrite);
```

Comment: Ok, it runs if I set it on my server, but how notepad and notepad++ do it?

Comment: They do it be ensuring that they use sharing options that make it clear they only intend to read the file and will allow other processes to write it while they are doing so. In order to achieve this, they use `fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone`. More information on the sharing options can be found in the help and of course on MSDN as the file sharing options are part of the file system which in turn is part of the OS.

Comment: Basically you use the sharing options to tell the file system how you want to open the file and what you will allow others to do when you have it open. If the file is already in use by another process and the sharing options set by that process are incompatible with the ones requested by you, your open will fail. Same applies when you are the first to open a file and another process opens it with sharing options incompatible with yours.

Comment: Marjan, I didn't understand. If i don't set this write flag on server, I'm not able to access the file, no matter if on my third application I set fmShareDenyWrite, like I said in the topic. So to do this I need to modify both of applications, but if I use notepad or notepad++ it's not necessary.

Comment: If you don't specify a sharing option, the default is fmShareCompat which "is compatible with the way that FCB's (File Control Blocks) are opened" (quoted from the help). Don't know what that means exactly, but it does mean that Notepad and Notepad++ are using a method of opening that is compatible with read-only access and FCB's.

Comment: Ok I'll study a little more about the answers, but notepad++ are able to read and write the archive.

Comment: @SaCi: Good idea (the study :-) Notepad++ may be able to write when you don't specify a sharing option (and thus use fmShareCompat), but it shouldn't be able to do so when you use fmShareDenyWrite. Although that may depend on the Delphi version as there was a bug in D2009 with regard to sharing options (don't remember the details).

Comment: Keep in mind that Notepad doesn't *keep* a file open. It opens it only long enough to copy it into memory or dump it to disk. While you're editing, Notepad does not retain any handle on the file

Answer (score 1):

I am using **Delphi7** and I was experiencing, that *TFileStream* sometimes fail to open a file for reading, while it is only locked for writing. (Before one would start nagging about the sharing parameters of the *TFileStream* class; I know about them, and set them right.) While I was not yet able to find out the reasons of this clearly buggy behavior, I found that it can be worked around by using some other means of file handling:

While the file can not be opened with *TFileStream* - even with the right sharing settings (yes, I know what I am doing) - it could easily be opened using the appropriate WinAPI calls: [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)/ReadFile/SetFilePointer/CloseHandle wrapped in the **Windows** unit.